# Expanding rows of pandas dataframe based on lookback window

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Given a dataframe of the form:

|  | date | window |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2009-01-01 00:00:00 | 2 |
| 1 | 2009-01-02 00:00:00 | 1 |
| 2 | 2009-01-03 00:00:00 | 3 |

Which can be generated by

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range(start='20090101', end='20090103')})
df['window'] = [2, 1, 3]
```

The goal is to create a row for each 'new_date' within the past 'window' of 'date'. Using the above dataframe as an example, the result should be:

|  | date | window | lookback | new_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2009-01-01 00:00:00 | 2 | 0 | 2009-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 0 | 2009-01-01 00:00:00 | 2 | 1 | 2008-12-31 00:00:00 |
| 0 | 2009-01-01 00:00:00 | 2 | 2 | 2008-12-30 00:00:00 |
| 1 | 2009-01-02 00:00:00 | 1 | 0 | 2009-01-02 00:00:00 |
| 1 | 2009-01-02 00:00:00 | 1 | 1 | 2008-12-31 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 2009-01-03 00:00:00 | 3 | 0 | 2009-01-03 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 2009-01-03 00:00:00 | 3 | 1 | 2009-01-02 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 2009-01-03 00:00:00 | 3 | 2 | 2008-12-31 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 2009-01-03 00:00:00 | 3 | 3 | 2008-12-30 00:00:00 |

My solution so far is

```
df['lookback'] = df['window'].apply(lambda x: range(x+1))
df = df.explode('lookback')
df['new_date'] = df[['date', 'lookback']].apply(lambda x: add_biz_dt(x[0], -x[1]), axis=1)
```

Note that add_biz_dt() is my internal method that takes a datetime first argument and numerical second argument, and gets the corresponding business date. I am constraint to use add_biz_dt.

I am trying to improve it so that it can be more efficient. There could be a better way than to use 'explode', and the 'apply' method seems especially inefficient.

Comment: Seems like you have two typos in your expected output. Can you *double-check* the last two new_dates ?

Comment: @Timeless Thanks for the answer. It is actually not a typo. The add_biz_dt custom function considers only business dates, and Jan 1 is not a business date.

Comment: BDs are quite chalenging but I update the answer below to handle that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible option (*without a custom func*) :

```
inp_cols = ["date", "window"]
out_cols = ["lookback", "new_date"]

lookbacks = (
    pd.DataFrame(
        [
            [range(0, w+1)] + [[d - pd.Timedelta(iw, unit="D")
              for iw in range(0, w+1)]] for d,w in df[inp_cols].to_numpy()])
    .explode([0, 1]).set_axis(out_cols, axis=1)
)

out = df.join(lookbacks)

# 2.41 ms ± 208 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Another variant (*x2 faster*) for the `lookbacks` without using [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) :

```
lookbacks = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [iw, d - pd.Timedelta(iw, unit="D")]
        for d,w in df[inp_cols].to_numpy() for iw in range(0, w+1) 
    ], index= df.index.repeat(df["window"].add(1)), columns=out_cols
)

# 1.16 ms ± 65.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

---

If you need to make sure to fall back to a business day, you can try :

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import CustomBusinessDay as CBD
from pandas.tseries.holiday import USFederalHolidayCalendar
UHC = USFederalHolidayCalendar()

lookbacks = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [iw, d - CBD(iw, calendar=UHC) if iw>0 else d]
        for d,w in df[inp_cols].to_numpy() for iw in range(0, w+1) 
    ], index= df.index.repeat(df["window"].add(1)), columns=out_cols
)
```

Output :

```
print(out)

        date  window  lookback   new_date
0 2009-01-01       2         0 2009-01-01
0 2009-01-01       2         1 2008-12-31
0 2009-01-01       2         2 2008-12-30
1 2009-01-02       1         0 2009-01-02
1 2009-01-02       1         1 2008-12-31
2 2009-01-03       3         0 2009-01-03
2 2009-01-03       3         1 2009-01-02
2 2009-01-03       3         2 2008-12-31
2 2009-01-03       3         3 2008-12-30
```